# Saving the state of my list view when back from details view on the same FrameLayout

Tags: android, listview

I have loaded a custom `ListView` in a `FrameLayout` in main page (MainActivity.java) but when scroll down I load second page and so on through the api. Then I click any list item and go to details view by replacing 
like -

> FragmentTransaction ft =
>   getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
>   ft.replace(R.id.fragment_content, pf, "current");

the list view by details view on the same `FrameLayout`. When I click back button and go to the list view I want the `listview` restore the same state that means the list view should hold the last visited state.

My requirements are if I go to details page and back the listview remain the same nothing change same state.

How way can I achieve this? Advance appreciation for quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Save the list view position in onSaveInstanceState and retrieve in OnCreate. Then set the position.